# Delay between lines while reading a file [ERROR]

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which reads a the contente of a file line by line.

```
 document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
 var file = this.files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
   var fileContentArray = this.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
   for (var line = 0; line < fileContentArray.length - 1; line++) {
     console.log(line + " --> " + fileContentArray[line]);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

**I know that the code to delay in JS it´s**

```
setTimeout(function() { 
}, 1000)
```

I want to show line by line but with a delay of 1 sec between lines

**But I´ve already to put it before the for loop and it doesn´t work.**

Comment: What is `lines` inside the `for` loop

Comment: @Nitheesh edited

Comment: @Updated the answer, please have a check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to execute your function in an interval.

Also don't forget to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) when the condition meets, or else the function will be non stop

**Sample Code**

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
    var fileContentArray = this.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    let index = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function() { 
      console.log(index + " --> " + fileContentArray[index]);
      ++index;
      if (index === lines.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000)
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Comment: It´s working, just need to declare the variable line.
 var line = 0;

Comment: You could make use of the variable `index` itself. It keeps track of your line number